# Google (And not TinEye) reverse image search API

Tags: search, web, asp.net-web-api, request, google-image-search

Any news about an official API for the reverse image search functionality of Google? TinEye is good, but it is not as good as Google!

I am thinking of creating a workaround, something like this:
[Google reverse image search using POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23270175/google-reverse-image-search-using-post-request)

Any other way?

Answer (score 0):

[Several](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55264636/1291371) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55023290/1291371) on [Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43700695/1291371) [Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58231736/1291371) suggest to use [`Google Vision API`](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/internet-detection) for reverse image search. I haven't used it so can't tell you whether it works as Google's `/searchbyimage/upload`.