# Google Custom Search Engine - search by image

Tags: google-api, google-search, google-search-api, google-custom-search, google-image-search

Right now I'm using Custom Search Engine (CSE) to search through entire web by search term. The request looks like:

```
GET "https:/www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_KEY&cx=SEARCH_ENGINE_ID&q=SEARCH_TERM"
```

And this request returns me list of search results.

But, I need to implement search by image or image url. Do Google API provide such a url param? Maybe something like "image_url"? So, the request can look the following:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=API_KEY&cx=SEARCH_ENGINE_ID&image_url=http://www.example.com/image.png
```

Basically, I need to implement the same functionality as images.google.com/ but using my Custom Search Engine. Thanks.

Example of what I need to implement:

[image: implement]

Comment: Answer to the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60892228/1291371

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, what you're looking for is only supported by [Vision AI](https://cloud.google.com/vision/) service (partially at least, never used it before). Google CSE API only allows you to search images and not **by** images as you may noticed.