# Search Google with image in Python

Tags: python, google-image-search

Is there a Google API that allows searching for images "by" images? Instead of a text query and getting image results for that, one would search with an image. I'm not looking to do web scraping with likes of selenium as this could break easily.

Comment: Do you want to do Reverse Image Search?

Comment: @Tanaike. Yes. Just like the "search google for image" context menu option in chrome.

Comment: Although unfortunately, this is not python script, is this information useful for you? https://github.com/tanaikech/goris

Comment: @Tanaike This seems good and is fairly recent. Will check into it thanks!

Comment: If this was useful for you, I'm glad.

Answer (score 2):

Google custom search now allows image only result but the search query is text only. What you want to do is reverse image search right? Then you may have a look at here: https://api.tineye.com/python/docs/ , but they are not free.

Comment: Although I prefer to stick to Google's product (because I know it gives me the results I want), it is nice to know there are other alternatives, will look into this, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Disclosure: I work at SerpApi.**

---

You can use [`google-search-results`](https://pypi.org/project/google-search-results) package to get data from Google Search by image URL. [Check a demo at Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/MagnificentAppropriateCodewarrior). Now it support search by `image_url` only.

```py
from serpapi.google_search_results import GoogleSearchResults

params = {
    "engine": "google_reverse_image",
    "google_domain": "google.com",
    "image_url": "https://i.imgur.com/HBrB8p0.png",
}

client = GoogleSearchResults(params)
data = client.get_dict()

print("Organic results\n")

for result in data['image_results']:
  print(f"""
Title: {result['title']}
Snippet: {result['snippet']}
""")
```

Response

```
{
  "image_results": [
    {
      "position": 1,
      "title": "Danny DeVito - Wikipedia",
      "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_DeVito",
      "displayed_link": "en.wikipedia.org › wiki › Danny_DeVito",
      "thumbnail": null,
      "snippet": "Daniel Michael DeVito Jr. (born November 17, 1944) is an American actor, director, producer, and screenwriter. He gained prominence for his portrayal of the ...",
      "cached_page_link": "https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:EVb7AC9xwHYJ:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_DeVito+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us",
      "related_pages_link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=related:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_DeVito&tbo=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGqMTdo7voAhVaxTgGHY-PAHMQHzAAegQIFBAH"
    },
    {
      "position": 2,
      "title": "Danny DeVito - IMDb",
      "link": "https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000362/",
      "displayed_link": "www.imdb.com › name",
      "thumbnail": null,
      "snippet": "Danny DeVito, Actor: Matilda. Danny DeVito has amassed a formidable and versatile body of work as an actor, producer and director that spans the stage, ...",
      "cached_page_link": "https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:c6r3v14HA7cJ:https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000362/+&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us"
    },
    {
      "position": 3,
      "title": "Fanny DeVito, the Danny DeVito Fanny Pack / Boing Boing",
      "link": "https://boingboing.net/2020/03/03/fanny-devito-the-danny-devito.html",
      "displayed_link": "boingboing.net › 2020/03/03 › fanny-devito-the-danny-devito",
      "thumbnail": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
      "date": "600 × 713 Mar 3, 2020",
      "snippet": "Fanny pack + Danny DeVito = Fanny DeVito, of course! This caught my eye because I recently discovered my 15-year-old daughter is aware of ...",
      "cached_page_link": "https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:32itW2-F6AsJ:https://boingboing.net/2020/03/03/fanny-devito-the-danny-devito.html+&cd=36&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us"
    },
    {
      "position": 4,
      "title": "The Church of Danny Devito - Home | Facebook",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/Dannydevotedtothecause/",
      "displayed_link": "www.facebook.com › ... › Religious Organization",
      "thumbnail": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
      "date": "807 × 960",
      "snippet": "The Church of Danny Devito, Philadelphia, Pennsylvania. 17K likes. Devoted to Devito."
    },
    {
      "position": 5,
      "title": "Danny DeVito (Creator) - TV Tropes",
      "link": "https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Creator/DannyDevito",
      "displayed_link": "tvtropes.org › Creator",
      "thumbnail": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
      "date": "350 × 415",
      "snippet": "A page for describing Creator: Danny DeVito. Daniel Michael DeVito, Jr. (born November 17, 1944) is an American actor, comedian, director, and producer.",
      "cached_page_link": "https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:xLRtMpAxLqAJ:https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Creator/DannyDevito+&cd=38&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us"
    },
    {
      "position": 6,
      "title": "Danny DeVito - Simple English Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia",
      "link": "https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_DeVito",
      "displayed_link": "simple.wikipedia.org › wiki › Danny_DeVito",
      "thumbnail": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
      "date": "1200 × 1427",
      "snippet": "Daniel Michael \"Danny\" DeVito, Jr. (born November 17, 1944) is an American actor, comedian, director and producer. He has starred in and directed a number ...",
      "cached_page_link": "https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:2DR2mxjaZbsJ:https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_DeVito+&cd=39&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us",
      "related_pages_link": "https://www.google.com/search?q=related:https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_DeVito&tbo=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiGqMTdo7voAhVaxTgGHY-PAHMQHzAmegQIDBAH"
    },
    {
      "position": 7,
      "title": "The Church of Danny DeVito - Home | Facebook",
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/DeVitite/",
      "displayed_link": "www.facebook.com › ... › Religious Organization",
      "thumbnail": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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",
      "date": "807 × 960",
      "snippet": "The Church of Danny DeVito. 1831 likes · 109 talking about this. This page is a dedicated meeting place for all devout DeVities and casual followers of..."
    }
  ]
}
```

Output

```
Organic results


Title: Danny DeVito - Wikipedia
Snippet: Daniel Michael DeVito Jr. (born November 17, 1944) is an American actor, director, producer, and screenwriter. He gained prominence for his portrayal of the ...


Title: Danny DeVito - IMDb
Snippet: Danny DeVito, Actor: Matilda. Danny DeVito has amassed a formidable and versatile body of work as an actor, producer and director that spans the stage, ...


Title: Fanny DeVito, the Danny DeVito Fanny Pack / Boing Boing
Snippet: Fanny pack + Danny DeVito = Fanny DeVito, of course! This caught my eye because I recently discovered my 15-year-old daughter is aware of ...


Title: The Church of Danny Devito - Home | Facebook
Snippet: The Church of Danny Devito, Philadelphia, Pennsylvania. 17K likes. Devoted to Devito.


Title: Danny DeVito (Creator) - TV Tropes
Snippet: A page for describing Creator: Danny DeVito. Daniel Michael DeVito, Jr. (born November 17, 1944) is an American actor, comedian, director, and producer.


Title: Danny DeVito - Simple English Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
Snippet: Daniel Michael "Danny" DeVito, Jr. (born November 17, 1944) is an American actor, comedian, director and producer. He has starred in and directed a number ...


Title: The Church of Danny DeVito - Home | Facebook
Snippet: The Church of Danny DeVito. 1831 likes · 109 talking about this. This page is a dedicated meeting place for all devout DeVities and casual followers of...
```

If you want more information, check out [SerpApi documentation](https://serpapi.com/google-reverse-image).